# Relógio do computador

Tags: c, linux

É possível calcular a diferença entre dois registos de tempo separados por menos de um segundo, utilizando o relógio do computador? Por exemplo, entre 12h00m00s000ms e 12h00m00s050ms.

Comment: Veja se lhe ajuda http://stackoverflow.com/a/16276032/221800

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da uma olhada sobre isso: clock_getres, clock_gettime, clock_settime
E aqui: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html

> ```
> int clock_getres(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec *res);
> ```
>
> A função `clock_getres()` acha a resolução (precisão) do relógio `clk_id` especificado, e, se `res` não é `NULL`, guarda o resultado na struct `timespec` apontada por `res`. A resolução dos relógios dependem da implementação e não podem ser configuradas por um processo em particular. Se o valor de tempo apontado pelo argumento `tp` de `clock_settime()` não for um múltiplo de `res`, então ele é truncado para um múltiplo de `res`.
>
> ```
> int clock_gettime(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec *tp);
> int clock_settime(clockid_t clk_id, const struct timespec *tp);
> ```
>
> As funções `clock_gettime()` e `clock_settime()` recuperam e atribuem o horário do relógio `clk_id` especificado.

Comment: A ideia de rejeitar respostas só com link não é só uma questão do link "sumir" ou não: é importante pra comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo, e em português. Se você não quer traduzir a documentação, você está no seu direito (aliás, vou dar uma ajudinha nisso... ;) ), mas poderia pelo menos colocar um exemplo de utilização, uma explicação informal sobre o que os métodos fazem, ou algo desse tipo.

Comment: P.S. Desculpa aí se achar que não foi certo eu editar sua resposta sem seu consentimento. Qualquer coisa, é só reverter pra revisão original.

Comment: O problema e que vc fiz a traduço de um "pedaço" da documentação. Sou Frances e temos em muitos casos o mesmo problema com documentação principalmente em Ingles. E posivel traduzir, certo. Mas neste caso, acho que Francisco não deve ficar somente com a tradução mas que ele deve ler a totalidade da doc. Boa sorte para ele! E muito obrigado para vôcé!

Comment: Claro, um link acompanhando a resposta é sempre bem vindo, mesmo que em outro idioma. O problema é quando a totalidade, ou quase totalidade, da resposta consiste no link.